# UCanAccess: truncate schema support not working

Tags: truncate, ucanaccess

any way to ucanaccess to supports HSQL`truncate schema PUBLIC and commit`?
it doesn't work on UCanAccess version 4.0.4

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UCanAccess does support several HSQLDB features as extensions to the Access SQL dialect, but it cannot support TRUNCATE TABLE and TRUNCATE SCHEMA because of the way UCanAccess synchronizes changes between the HSQLDB backing database and the Access database file.

As stated in the [HSQLDB documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_truncate_statement):

> TRUNCATE TABLE
>   ...
>   Delete all rows of a table without firing its triggers.
>
> ---
>
> TRUNCATE SCHEMA
>   ...
>   Performs the equivalent of a TRUNCATE TABLE ... AND COMMIT on all the
>   table in the schema.

UCanAccess relies on HSQLDB triggers to perform the synchronization.